# Name an entire enumerate environment in a way similar to cases environment

Tags: enumerate

I have an enumerate environment with 3 items in it, say H1, H2, and H3. I would like to reference this list as a whole, calling it H. Ideally, I could make an enumerate environment like cases and have H followed by a large left curly brace and then the enumerate environment for H1, H2, and H3. Is there a way to do this?

```
   _  
  /   H1
  |   
H<    H2
  |   
   \_ H3
```

Something like this, while being able to reference the whole list as \ref{H}.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cases` inside `enumitem`. To be able to reference the items of the `enumitem` you have to create a new float to wrap the whole thing in, in my example `enucase`, and put a label on the `\item` you want to refer to. This is a rough and ready solution but works. Just note that if you want to put normal text into the items following the curly bracket you have to wrap it `\text{}` or something similar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for cases and \text{}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % to define the Alphabetic enumerate label

\usepackage{float} % to create the new float
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{enucase}{tbhp}{loe}[section] %{float-name}{placement}{toc-style-list}[section reference]
\floatname{enucase}{Enumerated Case} %{float-name}{name-in-loe/toc}

\begin{document}

\section{Enumerated Cases with numbers}

\begin{enucase}
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item A
            \item\label{H} $ H =
            \begin{cases}
                one \\
                two \\
                three
            \end{cases}$
             \item B
            \end{enumerate}
\end{enucase}

    refers to Case \ref{H}
\section{Enumerated cases only with letters}

\begin{enucase}
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]
            \item bla bla bla
            \item\label{B} $ =
            \begin{cases}
                \text{item one} \\
                \text{item two} \\
                \text{item three}
            \end{cases}$
             \item bla bla
            \end{enumerate}
\end{enucase}

refers to Case \ref{B}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quite simple option (though you don't get the curly braces) is to put the enumerate inside of an equation using \parbox or minipage:

```
\begin{equation}\label{H}
    \parbox{15cm}{
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1cm]
         \item H1
         \item H2
         \item H3
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{equation}
```

You can play with the parbox's width and the indentation (I made it such that in my document it appears like a normal enumerate with the equation number that I will reference with to the right.)